# Flutter : How to use SharedPreference to get List<String>?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've create an initState in my page and call callData to get favId (type : List) every I open this page. But, when the application start, my compiler show this error message :

```
_TypeError (type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String')
```

and this is my getData's function :

```
getData(favId) async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return pref.getStringList(favId);
  }
```

also this is my saveData's function :

```
void saveData() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    pref.setStringList("id", favId);
  }
```

How to fix this problem and I can call getData every I open this page in my application?
Thank  you :)

Comment: Please do not treat Dart like JavaScript, just because you can. Dart is a proper programming language, use types instead of the automatic default of "dynamic". The type system will help you with proper error messages, so you can figure out what went wrong on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to save and retrieve List to and from SharedPreferences, you to use same key to save and retrieve the value.

here is a simple example,

```
const favKey = 'favoriteKey';
```

To save data,

```
void saveData(String favKey, List<String> favorites) async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    pref.setStringList(favKey,favorites);
  }
```

To retrive data,

```
getData(String favKey) async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return pref.getStringList(favKey);
  }
```

Note: You need to use same key to set and get data using SharedPreference.

Comment: wowww, now i can save and get data :D . But, why the data is just got it after pressing the favorite button? not when the page is opened?

Comment: `favId = getData();` do this in initState method.

Comment: there is error when I insert `favId = getData()` into initState. Here is the error : `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String' `

Comment: then you can define another function like `getIds()` in initState and outside of initState you can define `getIds() async { favId=getData();}`

Comment: `void initState() {super.initState(); getIds();}  getIds() async {favId = getData();}`

Comment: it doesn't even load anything when I restart my app :(

Comment: Solved Ranjid. I just add a setState in getData method :D Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

`"id"` is a String, you need to store a `List<String>` into `setStringList`

There are the steps if you want to add an item to the list:

```
List<String> ids = await getData(favId);
ids.add("id");
saveData(ids, favId);
```

then change the `saveData()` to

```
void saveData(ids, favId) async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    pref.setStringList(ids, favId);
}
```

`getData()`

```
List<String> getData(favId) async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return pref.getStringList(favId);
}
```

Comment: how about the getData ?

Comment: @BillRei Read the docs: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences#example